# Configure Grafana to alert only if the query matches for more than 4 minutes

Tags: mysql, grafana

I have a Grafana metrics like this:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as time_sec,
  sum(average_hashrate_eth) as value,
  'total hashrate' as metric
FROM status_rig
group by time;
```

With an alert like this:

`WHEN last()` of `query(A, 5m, now) IS BELOW 800`

How do I make this to only alert when this query is below 800 for more than 4 minutes only?

Thanks.

Comment: The "Evaluate every" is set to 60s. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Okay, and what is the expected output of the query for alert?

Comment: So as soon as the query is below 800 it will alert. I want it to only alert if it's below 800 for more than 5 minutes for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update your alert config to use:

WHEN max() of query(A, 4m, now) IS BELOW 800

Answer (score 0):

Assuming time-frequency of metric is 60 seconds and time is of `DATETIME` Type.

Try this:

```
  SELECT
   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as time_sec,
   SUM(case when average_hashrate_eth < 800 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as counter,
   SUM(average_hashrate_eth) as value,
   'total hashrate' as metric
  FROM status_rig
  WHERE time between (now()-interval 5 minute) and now()
  HAVING counter>=5;
```

This will give you the sum of `average_hashrate_eth` of last five minute from current time if value remains below 800

Comment: it gives this error:

`Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''total hashrate' as metric`

`FROM status_rig`

`WHERE time between (now()-interval ' at line 5`

Comment: Updated Query. check once